# DDD Which is the root Aggregate root?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Lots of examples like order and order lines makes sense, like:

`Order` is an **AR** that contains `OrderLines`
`Customer` is an **AR** that contains `Orders`.

Question is, what is the **AR** that contains `Customer`?
I guess it can be something like "shop".

So, `shop.AddCustomer(customer)`...

but, how to get shop?
If it's an **AR** (entity) it has an id, so `shop.GetById(shopId)`. If I only have one shop, how does this work with persistence?

Should I have a table (shops) with one line?
`Shop` is an in-memory object with a collection of `Customers`?

Answer (score 7):

You got that wrong there. **Aggregates do not contain other aggregates!** They can only reference them by ID.

An aggregate is a group of entities and value objects that are closely related. The aggregate forms a consistency boundary around them. The **Aggregate Root** is the root entity in that aggregate that is globally addressable. So in your example with `Order` and `OrderLines`, `Order` could indeed be the AR.

`Customer` on the other hand, would only reference `Orders` by ID if it is a separate aggregate.

To retrieve an aggregate, you typically use a *Repository*. You load an aggregate through the repository by specifying the ID of the aggregate, or some other suitable search parameter.

Comment: In which context do you create customers?

Comment: @BartCalixto You either instantiate it directly or use a factory (if construction is non-trivial). Then you pass the newly instantiated aggregate to the repository, e.g. `customerRepo.create(theNewCustomer)`

Comment: @theDmi When you say Customer would only reference Orders by ID (e.g. $customer->getOrders()), would getOrders() only return an array of ID's or would it return an Orders object?

Comment: @Jonathan That's the logical consequence of proper aggregate design. It would only return a list of IDs. If that is a major problem for a specific domain, then the aggregate boundaries are probably wrong. The separation here is just an example.

Comment: I'd argue that the `Order` shall reference the `CustomerId` rather than the opposite if no special invariant has to be enforced such as a maximum number of active orders... and even then...

Comment: @theDmi OK that makes sense but here is another example that confuses me, let's say we have two aggregate roots Author and Book. Does $author->get books() return an array of book IDs or a BookAggregate object that contains the array of Book IDs?

Comment: @Jonathan That's just the same example again! Aggregates should never have navigable relations to other aggregates, no matter how you twist and turn the examples.

Comment: @Jonathan I guess you meant `$bookRepo->getAllByAuthorId($author->authorId)`.