# Using one Repository Inside Another

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I am new to DDD, I have a Partner aggregate which has an User reference.
The User object itself is another Aggregate.

Since not all users has to be referenced in the Partner object, the User object is an aggregate root.
The Partner is an aggregate root as well.

First:
Would my design be wrong with one aggregate root inside another?

Second:
If the design is right, would it be a bad practice to use one Repository inside another to persiste the Partner? (UserRepository inside PartnerRepository)

Obs: I am not using any ORM framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DDD Which is the root Aggregate root?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423613/ddd-which-is-the-root-aggregate-root)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am new to DDD...

I'll be answering this from a DDD standpoint, not OOP (Object Oriented Programming).

> First: Would my design be wrong with one aggregate root inside
>   another?

It wouldn't follow the general guidelines of Domain-Driven Design.  If you want to reference one aggregate root from another, you would reference it by id.

> Second: If the design is right, would it be a bad practice to use one
>   Repository inside another to persiste the Partner? (UserRepository
>   inside PartnerRepository)

Again if following the guidelines of DDD, you wouldn't do this, you would persist each aggregate separately using separate repositories.

[Here's a link to an article by Vaughn Vernon](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=4), possibly the second greatest figure in the field of DDD to explain better.

Comment: NoooooOoo!! OOP and referencing by Id? Do you mean, for example, `User.RoleId` instead of `User.Role`????????

Comment: In the original poster's scenario it would be `Partner.UserId` to reference a completely separate `User` aggregate by id (not an object reference).  This is specifically a DDD thing and not general OOP.

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify that this is a DDD specific answer.

Comment: Sorry but I doubt that DDD could say that you should associate domain objects this way...............

Comment: It does.  I've added a link to my answer to explain more if you wish to learn more about DDD.  Don't panic though, DDD provides patterns like CQRS to deal with the query model.

Comment: BTW, he's not Eric Evans, and anyway, the link proposal is an horrible OOP design, and this is a fact. Because he feels that holding object associations can lead to modify objects which shouldn't be modified within a domain transaction, he downgrades OOP. This could be constrained in many ways, for example using the specification pattern to check that only the objects within the domain are modified during the transaction.

Comment: IMHO, unless you're in a non-OOP language, your proposal is horrible, and I believe that DDD isn't a good paradigm for things like CQRS, even when some are trying to force it to go this way.

Comment: And I don't panic because of DDD. Your proposal breaks basic OOP principles.......

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I disagree with every single comment that you made in response to this answer. DDD is about being able to manage large domain models by *breaking it up in a meaningful way*. One important tool to achieve this is the concept of an aggregate, which should be modeled exactly how Adrian describes. Referencing by ID is not the tool of choice when doing OOP, but in selected cases, it is a good thing. Otherwise you end up with one big connected object model. How would that even scale?

Comment: @theDmi Lazy-loading.

Comment: @theDmi In the other hand, most DDD implementations are tied to OOP. Even most design patterns are designed to work in OOP scenarios. For me, using relations over associations in OOP languages (and I doubt that one would be implementing DDD in C, BASIC or even ASM) is a design flaw and it breaks the data source independence from the domain, because *associating by id* couples your domain to relational stores if you want to work efficiently...

Comment: @theDmi OP says isn't using an OR/M. But one of most important design patterns to easily implement a repository is *data mapper*. Even NoSQL databases may need a *data mapper* (obviously, it won't be an OR/M).

Comment: The *"reference other aggregates by ID"* recommendation was not part of the original DDD blue book but a contribution from Vaughn Vernon's red book. Still, it can be a useful approach. I don't agree with everything Vaughn says but I don't see why this particular point would violate any core OO principle.

Answer (score 2):

> First: Would my design be wrong with one aggregate root inside another?

Yes.

> **AGGREGATE** 
>   A cluster of associated objects that are treated as a unit for the purpose of data changes.  External references are restricted to one member of the aggregate, designated as the root.  A set of consistency rules applies within the aggregate's boundaries.

[Eric Evans, Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)

The problem your design faces is this: the Partner aggregate cannot protect its own invariant if the User aggregate is allowed to modify the same state independently.

When, in your design, you assert that X is an aggregate, you are making two claims

1. The validity of any change to X can be determined without consulting any external state.
2. The validity of any external change can be determined without consulting the state of X.

That's the aggregate boundary -- changes on the outside don't need to look inside, changes inside don't need to look outside.

Therefore, nesting aggregates is a contradiction.

Another way of expressing the same idea: if one aggregate root is inside another, then you have an aggregate (the Partner aggregate) which has *two* roots (the Partner entity, and the User entity), which is precisely the situation that the aggregate pattern is intended to avoid.

Possible remedies:

One is that the User *entity* really is part of the Partner aggregate.  Every change to the user is supposed to be managed by the Partner.  You move the User back into the partner aggregate, and prevent your implementation from accessing it except by issuing commands to the aggregate root.

Another is that the User *entity* isn't part of the Partner aggregate.  Then you eliminate the direct reference in the Partner; that might mean eliminating the reference completely (if the business rules of Partner don't depend upon user at all), or having a reference to the User identifier, and business rules that check the identifier *without* following it (in other words, your rules might check that an id reference is null/not null, or is/is not a member of a collection).  If you think about it, the Partner aggregate can't even tell if the User it is referencing **exists**.

A third is the discovery of a new entity in your model, that includes the part of User that the Partner aggregate actually uses for validation.  This might be a snapshot of User state, or it might be a refactoring of User into multiple pieces.

Answer (score -2):

> First: Would my design be wrong with one aggregate root inside
>   another?

I doubt it. For example, `User` can be the aggregate root of some domain called *user management* and `UserProfile` the aggregate root of some other domain called *user profiles*, and probably there should be a `1:1` association between both domain objects.

> Second: If the design is right, would it be a bad practice to use one
>   Repository inside another to persiste the Partner? (UserRepository
>   inside PartnerRepository)

You should ensure that there's a clear separation of concerns and you follow the *single responsibility principle*. That is, a repository can handle a single domain object and injecting a repository inside of other one opens the door to handle related or unrelated domain objects.

My advise is you should represent transactions in your domain services, and there you can inject as many repositories as you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
In the design I have a UserRole object in my User, this UserRole references the Partner, so when I insert the Partner I would have to insert first the Partner without the user so I could get the Partner reference id, then persist the User with the UserRole.
This is why I would need a the UserRepository inside the Partner Repository so it could handle the insertion of a Partner as an aggregate.
I guess the design of the relation of the UserRole and user is the tricky part of the design.

Comment: @MarcoPrado Maybe I'm mistaken, but both users and roles should exist before persisting the partner :O

Comment: Sorry I'll try to explain. A user May be attached to many partners so each UserRole must correspond to a relation with a partner so each User May have one or more UserRole each referencing the Partners, but a Patner must have a User in the meaning of the user owning the Partner and this relation is also expressed via a UserRole in the User model

Comment: @MarcoPrado BTW I don't see why you can't implement everything as I've already explained in my answer. Since you said you're not using an OR/M, obviously you'll need to implement a lot of code, but AFAIK your question is tech-agnostic...

Comment: I understand that I'm getting downvotes because of my negative point of view of associating objects by id, because excepting this, the rest of my answer (which was published before the selected one by the other author) has almost the same content and I also add the thing about implementing transactions using domain services... It would be great that downvoters could explain what's wrong to improve my answer. Thanks.